# Dimensions of object in R

Tags: r, dimension

Whenever I need to find out number of rows in dataframe, I use `nrow(df)` or `dim(df)`. I need to find out number of rows in series I use `NROW(df$col_1)`. Is there one function, which works in both cases?

Comment: I think `NROW()` works in both cases

Comment: @apom Wow, indeed! Thank you so much!